# Is there a graphical keyboard for ibus?

Tags: gui, language, ibus

I am in the US and use a US-layout keyboard. However, I am doing a Korean language class and have a need to be able to type in Korean. I have downloaded and installed ibus with the korean language pack; however, I am finding it difficult to use, as I am having to guess where the keys are for the Korean letters.

Is there a graphical keyboard available in Linux that would allow me to pick Korean letters using the mouse (similar to a smart phone)? Perhaps there is a feature in ibus somewhere that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

`xvkbd` seems to have a Korean layout built-in. Otherwise try
[alternativeto](https://alternativeto.net/software/onboard-on-screen-keyboard/?platform=linux)
which lists florence, maliit, and onboard
Also, not what you want, but `gkbd-keyboard-display` (which doesnt need gnome desktop) shows you a keyboard and highlights the keys as you type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't seen `xvkbd` before, but I will give it a try and some of the other ones you listed, if that doesn't help.